# How to echo button with onclick function using foreach and condition in php?

Tags: javascript, php, css, button, foreach

Expect:

Select data from my SQL.
Foreach to echo data and the button.
When the data is null, display the "join" button with onclick function.
When the data is "joined", hide the "join"button with onclick function, display the "result" button with onclick function.

Result:

Cannot hide the "join"button with onclick function, display the "result" button with onclick function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    
         $servername = "localhost";
         $username = "root";
         $password = "";
         $dbname = "battle";
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM battleRecord Group by id");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                        
            foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
              if ($row['participation'] == 'joined') {
                $displayJoin = 'none';
                $displayResult = 'block';
            } else {
                $displayJoin = 'block';
                $displayResult = 'none';
            }
               ?>

              <tr>
              <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>                                
              <p><?php echo $row['id']?></p>
            
              </td>  
              <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>                                
              <button style="display:<?php echo $displayJoin ?>" id="joinBattle" onclick="joinBattle(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>)">joinbattle</button>
              
              <button style="display:<?php echo $displayResult ?>" id="checkResult" onclick="checkResult(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['result']) ?>)">result</button>
              
              </td>  
              </tr>
                                                
              <?PHP

                }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
                  $conn = null;
                  
                   ?>

   
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Result and Mysql

[MySQL part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKXbj.png)

[MySQL part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhip2.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUMC1.png)

[View Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjiwR.png)

Comment: Changed it. Hope you can help me to solve the echo button using foreach and condition too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set `$displayJoin` to `block`. Use this:

```
if ($row['participation'] == 'joined') {
    $displayJoin = 'none';
    $displayResult = 'block';
} else {
    $displayJoin = 'block';
    $displayResult = 'none';
}
```

Comment: I  try your way before but the system shows both "join" button and "result" button when($row['participation'] == 'joined' .

Comment: I don't see how that could be.

Comment: Make sure you removed all the original code that assigns these variables.

Comment: sure. I just test using the above code. The result shows both buttons. I have upload the image, please check it. Thank you.

Comment: Your edit says `$row["battlefield_empireParticipation"])=="none"` but the code says `$row['participation']`. Which is it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows 3 join buttons on the same row, and 1 result button on the next row. I don't see how you're getting that from this code. It has two buttons on each row and hides one of them.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I review the code and show the result and MySQL for all.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't change the code in the question to my answer. Now no one will see what the original problem was that I tried to fix.

Comment: Got it. Mr Barmar.

Comment: What do you see if you use `View Source`? Does it have the expected `style` attributes?

Comment: It shows "Undefined variable: displayjoin"

Comment: You have a typo in `<?php echo $displayjoin ?>`, that should be `$displayJoin` with an uppercase `J`